# What version of Windows Installer is installed by default in OS?

Tags: operating-system, windows-installer, windows-server-2008, windows-vista, windows-server-2003

Help determine what version of Windows Installer is installed by default in operating systems?

Help Please fill in the table below:

```
Windows XP                    Windows Installer 2.0 
Windows XP (SP1)              Windows Installer 3.0
Windows XP (SP2)              Windows Installer 3.0 
Windows XP (SP3)              Windows Installer 3.1 
Windows XP RTM                Windows Installer 3.0 
Windows XP 64-bit Edition     **???**

Windows Server 2003           Windows Installer 2.0 
Windows Server 2003(SP1)      Windows Installer 3.1 
Windows Server 2003(SP2)      **???**
Windows Server 2003 RTM       Windows Installer 3.0 

Windows Server 2003 R2 (x64)(x86)        **???**
Windows Server 2003 R2(SP1)(x64)(x86)    **???**
Windows Server 2003 R2(SP2)(x64)(x86)    **???**

Windows Vista                 **???**   
Windows Vista (SP1)           Windows Installer 4.0
Windows Vista (SP2)           Windows Installer 4.5

Windows Server 2008           **???**
Windows Server 2008 (SP1)     Windows Installer 4.0
Windows Server 2008 (SP2)     Windows Installer 4.5 

Windows Server 2008 R2        Windows Installer 5.0 
Windows Server 2008 R2(SP1)   Windows Installer 5.0 

Windows 7                     Windows Installer 5.0 
Windows 7 (SP1)               Windows Installer 5.0 

Windows 8                     Windows Installer 5.0 

Windows Server 2012           Windows Installer 5.0
```

Comment: Refer to the excellent entry on [InstallSite](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1001.htm)